# Bind mousewheel Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, bind, mousewheel

I am trying to bind the mousewheel to an frame widget that has labels and buttons displayed on it and I the problem is that it works only when I have the cursor of mouse in a empty area of frame widget. If I move the mouse on one of the button or label that has this frame as parent, the program doesn't bind my mousewheel anymore.
How can I fix this?
I am using this expression:

```
frame.bind("<MouseWheel>", mouse_wheel)
```

Also I noticed that if I bind it to root (root.bind("", mouse_wheel)), it works (executes the mouse_wheel function) even if my mouse is located anywhere on tkinter window (even if it's located over buttons and labes). I do not want to bind to root, because I want to bind only the area of frame widget.

Comment: Hello Gheorghe, could you attach your entire code or the section that is not working as expected?

Comment: Your questions title are contradict to your explanation: ***to bind the mousewheel...***. Please update accordingly to one of it. Pick one from [`[tkinter] Mousewheel`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+%5Btkinter%5D+Mousewheel)